# Java WebApp: ClassNotFoundException com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory

Tags: java, maven, servlets, web-applications, rabbitmq

I have the following maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

And i have the following servlet:

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

import model.DVD;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public IndexServlet()
    {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

        try
        {

            /// some code

            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHost("localhost");
            Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
            channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, obj.getBytes());
            System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + dvd.getName() + "'");

            channel.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (IOException | TimeoutException | NumberFormatException exp)
        {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

        response.sendRedirect("/A3_Producer/");
    }

}
```

I run Maven build with clean install and after that I start the web application in a tomcat server. The welcome page loads, but when I hit the Submit button and enter in this servlet, I get an `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to make a `ConnectionFactory` object.

I added the jar too to build path but it didn't fix the problem.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: add this package com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory to WEB-INF/classes and then run

Comment: Your `<dependency>` is not declared in the `<dependencyManagement>` section, is it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work, you need to place the client jar into the `tomcatinstallation/lib` lib folder. (`$CATALINA_HOME/lib`)